# What is Sacla?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Is Sacla a standard library for lisp? What does it do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Sacla](http://homepage1.nifty.com/bmonkey/lisp/sacla/index-en.html) is an implementation of Common Lisp in Lisp. Thus it does include the standard library but also includes the whole language.

The project seems abandoned since 2004.

Answer (score 0):

[Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) is a programming language. AFAIK it has nothing to do with Lisp

Comment: One could say Scala is inspired by Lisp, since it is partly a functional language. And Lisp is more or less the oldest functional language still in use today.

Comment: @darioo I guess, but Scala code just doesn't strike me as very Lisp-like: there are hardly any parentheses anywhere!

Comment: @Jakub The title said Sacla, the text said Scala :-(

Comment: There's [a deleted answer by OP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5530144/1281433) that says, "Scala NO ! Sacla , it related to LISP."  OP is asking about Sacla, not Scala.